# Is there a good way to use Node and PHP in conjunction

Tags: php, node.js, e-commerce

Recently I have become quite attached to JavaScript. I have begun learning frameworks such as React and Vue and have set up a fully operational Node environment on my laptop with webpack and Babel etc. These things have made development a lot easier and I feel happier about the apps I am making.

I want to make an E-commerce website for a project I am required to do in school. There is no credit given for JavaScript but I can use it if I want to.

PHP on the other hand is an option. I need to integrate with a database and I'm familiar with both MySQL and PostgreSQL so thats not an issue. However I can't see a good way to use both Node and PHP in conjunction and Node can do what PHP can in a more elegant way in my mind (correct me if I'm wrong).

So basically can somebody tell me if it's possible to use frameworks like React and Vue to create the front end of my application and then pass data back and forth between the framework and PHP? Or should I for go the JavaScript Frameworks altogether and just write the whole application in PHP?

Thanks in advance, I'd like to add I have looked around on Staxk for answers and failed to find any that seemed super relevant or up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are conflating Node.JS, which is server-side JavaScript, with frontend development frameworks, such as Vue and React. While it is possible to use React to achieve server-side rendering, you can use React solely on the client-side. As a result, you are asking two questions:

**Can you use PHP with React/Vue/Client-side Javascript?**
Yes, absolutely. Given that PHP is entirely server-side, if you wish to use a powerful front-end framework, you will need to use Javascript.

**Is there a good way to use Node and PHP in conjunction?**
Not really. I have had development environments where I have used PHP alongside Node, usually with Redis in between, but this was to achieve very specific things, and I would not recommend deploying this in a production environment. However, for a project, if you are attempting to achieve specific things, and you only have limited development time, it is possible to link them together.

Ultimately, it sounds like you're already happy enough with Node.JS to not have to use it alongside PHP, and since you are keen to use Javascript heavily on the frontend, it might be best to use it on the backend as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful.